# Sum of first part of string in an array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array of strings from which I need to extract the first words, convert them to integers and get the their sum.

Example:

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"]
```

Expected output =>  `25`

My attempt:

```
["5","5","15"].map(&:to_i).sum
```

Comment: `array.map(&:split).map(&:first)` or `array.map { |x| x.split.first }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map with [`#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split):

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"].map{|s| s.split.first.to_i }.sum
=> 25
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer from your question.

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"].map(&:to_i).sum
```

In array if any integer convertable value is present then it will automatically convert into integer.

Answer (score 4):

`String#to_i` looks for digits at the start of the string and converts them to integers:

```
'Foo'.to_i   # => 0
'5 Bar'.to_i # => 5
'Baz 5'.to_i # => 0
```

Hence just sum the result of `to_i`:

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"].sum(&:to_i) # => 25
```

Comment: `sum` is enough. It has just the Ruby version as a constraint.

Comment: @SebastianPalma OP's question included `sum` so I suppose they have a relevant version. Even if they don't it's fairly likely they use ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"].sum { |w| w.split(' ').first.to_i }
```

Would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is now the most popular question in the Ruby section, so here's another way:

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"].reduce(0) {|sum,n| sum + n.to_i}
```

Or as suggested by @EricDuminil, just:

```
["5 Apple", "5 Orange", "15 Grapes"].sum(&:to_i)
```

Comment: @EricDuminil You're right, I've edited my answer. I'll delete it if you want to post it. Seems like the optimal solution here, too. Thanks for the suggestion